JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook Port Conflict Between Windows and Linux
In my setup, I have JupyterLab running on http://localhost:8859/doc and Jupyter Notebook on http://localhost:8858/notebooks/new_proj. On Windows, both services use the same port (8858), but on Linux, they require different ports (8858 for Jupyter Notebook and 8859 for JupyterLab) to function properly. How can I resolve this issue?
"I am trying to start the server with 2 ports on Linux, but it's not working; however, it works fine on Windows."

Cross-posted without reference here.

I see you marked it as solved on the Jupyter Discourse? Could you then put here or there what helped you resolve your question?
